# How to use viewpager inside collapsible toolbar?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using Viewpager at the top of my layout and below that there is a frame layout which contains a recycler View. I want to collapse the viewpager when i scroll my recycler view so that it can be viewed full screen.

This is how my layout file looks like:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/seperator"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I have attached the screenshort also for the same.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Using **`CoordinatorLayout`** you can do this.

Follow this `Layout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="false" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**EDIT 1:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:fillViewport="false"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: As you can see in screenshot i posted, viewpager is at the top of the screen and i want to collapse it on scroll of below recycler view. The code you have sent as answer is having viewpager but it is outside collapsabletoolbar.

Comment: @Abhishek Check with updated answer. it will collapse view pager below toolbar when you scroll up.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below link you can find how to use `CoordinatorLayout`  and `CollapsingToolbarLayout` also in this link they have used `TabLayout` and `ViewPager`

https://gist.github.com/iPaulPro/1468510f046cb10c51ea

Comment: Viewpager is used outside of collapsingtoolbar. I want to collapse the view pager only

Answer (score 0):

Put your View Pager inside an Collapsing Toolbar layout and use coordinator layout.

Have a look at the link below. Understand it and start implementing. Any doubts feel free to ask me here.

http://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/

Once you are done with that also have a look at below link.

[Collapsing Toolbar and Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302053/collapsing-toolbar-and-fragment)

Comment: I am doing the same but my layout is getting messy. Can you please edit my layout file?

Comment: What happned? I am waiting for your response. Please help

Comment: jaydroider is onto it. Have a look at his answer

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED:**

First you need to compile

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
```

and then here is the sample

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
          <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I have edited it to make as simple for you as i could, Hope it helps

Comment: But in your code viewpager is outside the collipsingtoolbar. I want to collapse the view pager only.