# How to use ViewPager2 with CollapsibleToolbar layout

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am trying to achieve something with `collapsible toolbar` layout and I have 2 tabs with a `viewPager2`

Below are two images for example for the case of [expanded screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5qmH.png) and [collapsed screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKbTe.png).

Below is the code I have in XML not sure where it is going wrong... my scroll is not working proper in this case. I want the toolbar to be stick on top when collapsed

I tried adding `toolbar` inside `AppbarLayout` but that didn't worked.

Also tried below links
somehow not working for me [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302053/collapsing-toolbar-and-fragment?noredirect=1&lq=1) [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37042684/how-to-use-viewpager-inside-collapsible-toolbar)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white_dark_blue">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white_cream_darkest_blue"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/white_cream_darkest_blue"
                app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@color/text_color"
                app:contentScrim="@color/white_cream_darkest_blue"
                app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@color/text_color"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:statusBarScrim="@color/white_cream_darkest_blue">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_start"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_end"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
                        style="@style/screen_title"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                        android:text="Mailing\nAddress"
                        android:textColor="@color/text_color" />

                    <TextView

                        android:id="@+id/textViewSubTitle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
                        android:text="We'll send your bill to this address."
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:visibility="gone" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="30dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_start"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_end"
                    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
                    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/text_service"
                    app:title="">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/menuOption"
                        style="@style/screen_sub_title"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                        android:text="Mailing Address"
                        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:visibility="gone" />


                </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabLayoutMailingAddress"
                    style="@style/tabLayoutStyle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_start"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_end"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:tabInlineLabel="true"
                    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyCustomTextAppearance" />

                <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                    android:id="@+id/viewPagerMailingAddress"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="1.2"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabLayoutMailingAddress" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ViewPager2` won't work well inside `NestedScrollView` as its inner `RecyclerView` enables the nested scrolling by default.

To fix the misbehavior, you need to disable this nested scrolling of the `ViewPager2` `RecyclerView` programmatically as it's not accessible in layout:

Kotlin:

```
viewPager.children.find { it is RecyclerView }?.let {
    (it as RecyclerView).isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
}
```

Java:

```
for (int i = 0; i < viewPager.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View child = viewPager.getChildAt(i);
    if (child instanceof RecyclerView) {
        ((RecyclerView) child).setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: So the reason why I am using ```ViewPager2``` is I have a couple of ```EditText``` which I need for user input.

Comment: Are those of the `TabLayout` tabs?

Comment: I have 2 Tabs ... each tabs (has a fragment) and has multiple editTexts inside both fragments (you can check in screenshots attached in the question) 
Collapsed and Expanded ones

Comment: So, those fragments are the pages of the ViewPager; scrolling them to have the collapsing effect still shows a problem?

Comment: Umm kinda yes ... your code somewhat resolved my issue but it just stops scrolling as soon as the toolbar is collapsed at the top... then I am not able to scroll more

Comment: Nevermind Zain I figured out my issue .... I was able to resolve it in ```ViewPager``` I had ```android:layout_height="0dp"
                    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="1.2"``` 

which was creating issue now it seems to be working

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Good job.. I guess you could constraint the viewpager to the bottom

Comment: One last thing If you know where I can understand more on Why ```ViewPager2``` not good with ```NestedScrollView```. Any article or google issue you came across?

Comment: I came across this issue; it's not something special to the `NestedScrollView`; sorry if I didn't express it well; I meant when VP2 wrapped in another scrolling view in general; I had something similar to that; let me check if there is something useful online

Comment: No worries! just curious to know more about it. Appreciate it!

Comment: See [this issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123006042)  pls; it is a mix of this issue; and another issue of the nested scrolling views of ViewPager2; it also discussed by documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration#nested-scrollables)