# Android header fade in and out on scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

Can anyone give me a shortcut way to implement fade-in and fade-out `Toolbar` for this xml setup?

**To say:** for unavoidable reason, `ViewPager` is a child of `FrameLayout`. If i could bring it in this `xml` file I could implement it.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.lecet.fin.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/points"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:text="text"/>    

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="110dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/greyish"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/black"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_tab" /> 

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Whats the issue than? It doesnt collapse ?

Comment: No, it doesn't because child of `FrameLayout` doesn't scroll. What scrolls is its child of child. `Framelayout` -> `ViewPager` -> `ListView`

Comment: ``app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`` to the viewPager will help ?

Comment: No, it's still the same. Any way to do it by `listview.OnScrollListener`?

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302053/collapsing-toolbar-and-fragment

Comment: It won't work because I cannot replace `FrameLayout` with `ViewPager`.

Comment: did you added all the things specified in that

Comment: Yes I double checked it. `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` added in `AppBarLayout` and `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. Doesn't work

Comment: Add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to  `ViewPager` and `ListView` and check

Comment: Tried in `FrameLayout`, `ViewPager`, `ListView` individually and all along. It doesn't work. I mean no effect on header.